# How to display a badge with pending notifications number on IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, badge

On android, when you have pending notifications, the icon of the app will display a circle for telling the user that pending notifications exists for the app, you don't need to implement anything or adding code to the app. On iOS I see that some apps display that circle, even including a number of pending notifications. How can that be implemented? I can't find any official documentation about that.

The only think I can find is this: https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/1301

There, an answer says that on IOS you need to include this playload:

> iOS differs from Android with regards to the badge-count. While on
> Android it is directly connected to the number of unhandled recieved
> notifications on iOS it's dependent upon what you yourself set it to.
>
> You need to include the badge-count in the payload:

```
{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "You got your emails.",
        "badge" : 9
    }
}
```

Where whould be included that playload? And which code whould be added in swift inside the ios application to display the badge with the number of pending notifications?

Comment: [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/generating_a_remote_notification) is the documentation. And you have to set the badge in code with [`applicationIconBadgeNumber`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622918-applicationiconbadgenumber)

Comment: @vadian thank you very much, so it is necessary to add code, but in the second link you provide, they talk only about a function called "applicationIconBadgeNumber" but they don't explain where should I use that function and how should I use it.

Comment: It's supposed to be called on the shared instance of the application `UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 9`. And make sure that's being called on the main thread.

Comment: @vadian I don't understand you. Does apple provide a guide of how to use this function? I don't know what you mean with shared instance of the application, and where are you getting that "9"?

Comment: Here is the documentation about the User Notification Framework: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/. And please search for Apple Push Notifications or APNS. There are a lot of tutorials.